# Generar el el mismo hash generado con JavaScript pero con C# o Visual Basic .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

//Este es el código que quiero pasar de JavaScript a C#
//Necesito que estas dos funciones puedan ejecutarse en C# o Visual Basic .NET

```
  hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64url(request.data), apiSecret);


    function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    // first we use encodeURIComponent to get percent-encoded UTF-8,
    // then we convert the percent encodings into raw bytes which
    // can be fed into btoa.
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
        function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}


function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
        function toSolidBytes(match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
    }));
}
```

Comment: intentaste algo?

Comment: me falto esta parte del codigo
 hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64url(request.data), apiSecret); 

Intente varias cosas pero nunca genero el mismo hash en C#

Comment: Agrega eso en la pregunta

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue

Comment: Estas conciente de que te estas saltando cierta informacion importante?, como por ejemplo el hecho de que CryptoJS `NO` existe en javascript puro?, entonces como pasar algo que no existe en javascript a algo que talvez solo este disponible para javascript?, a lo que me refiero es que nos estas pidiendo recrear una libreria entera en C# y .net: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/.

Comment: @Riven, no necesariamente. Crypto es una librería que implementa algoritmos muy conocidos y utilizados. De hecho implementa algoritmos estándar. El algoritmo usado por el OP es [`hmac`](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) en su versión `SHA256`. La teoría criptográfica establece que si aplicas el mismo algoritmo a la misma cadena, se produce el mismo `hash`, independientemente del lenguaje usado. No hay que escribir una librería. Y seguro el lenguaje C# ya dispone de un [algoritmo `hash`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Es cierto, aunque no me referia a eso... es cierto que el puede solo reconstruir la funcion de la libreria que le interesa, quiza no lo plantee bien, a lo que me referia era que esa funcion que esta intentando ejecutar de esa libreria en javascript no existe directamente, tendriamos que entonces nosotros crear esa funcion, porque hasta donde se no existe, la idea seria que el usuario primero intentase el mismo crear esa funcion, para saber como plantearla en `C#`, de otra manera le estariamos haciendo todo el trabajo.

Comment: Claro, perfecto. Es hacer esta misma funcion que construye un hash en .net